# Why isn't this math.log function working?

Tags: javascript, logarithm

I'm having trouble with calculating a logarithm and using the answer as a variable. Can anyone help?

Here's an example - the simple 4*4 calculation appears when the first button is clicked, but nothing happens when the math.log(100) function's button is clicked...

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript">

function Multiply(form)
{
var m = 4*4;
form.MultiOut.value = m;
}

function Log(form)
{
var l = math.log(100);
form.LogOut.value = l;
}
</script>

<FORM>
A normal calculation - 4*4:
<INPUT NAME="calc" VALUE="Calculate" TYPE=BUTTON 
onClick=Multiply(form)>
<INPUT NAME="MultiOut" SIZE=15>
<br>
A log function calculation:
<INPUT NAME="calc" VALUE="Calculate" TYPE=BUTTON 
onClick=Log(form)>
<INPUT NAME="LogOut" SIZE=15>
</FORM>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: there is no `math` object in javascript, but there is one `Math`

Answer (score 6):

Because `math.log(100)` should be `Math.log(100)`. (Capital "M")

Open your browser's developer console to see the error message.